# How much version of Android supports Unity 2017.4.20?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello I made a game i unity 2017.4.20 
so if I have sdk completely ( all api ), unity 2017.4.20 support all android versions for example: android 9  or 8.1  ?
and can I build My game for android 9 with unity 2017.4.20?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `AndroidSdkVersions` there you can see which Android SDK versions are supported by the according Unity version.

For [Unity 2017.4](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/AndroidSdkVersions.html) the maximum level is

```
AndroidApiLevel27   Android 8.1, "Oreo", API level 27.
```

---

```
AndroidApiLevel28   Android 9.0, "Pie", API level 28.
```

was added in [Unity 2018.3](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/AndroidSdkVersions.html)

---

Some general stuff like `64 bit` and App bundle support was [backported](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/03/05/android-support-update-64-bit-and-app-bundles-backported-to-2017-4-lts/) into Unity `2017.4 LTS` but I guess that didn't change the maximum supported API level.